# Controll Java Swing Application over Bluetooth

Tags: java, swing, bluetooth

Any one know about how to Controll Java Swing application with Bluetooth on any other device from Java, Android, J2ME Application ? I'm ask for an Example from someone.

I've already discovered Bluetooth devices. Now I want to Connect with device and I have a swing application and I want to send some Commands and Data from Bluetooth. I want some example dear! I want to Know how to do this, Please just give me some example if anyone can HELP me.

Comment: Hey, your not just going to get solutions here. You need to show that you have made an attempt. What have you tried? What is your problem?

Comment: I tried to do something new dear, I just want to Exchange data over Bluetooth from Swing Application(specially). Can you give me some sample code for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come across [this code](http://vision.middlebury.edu/~ascooper/cs500/) before which someone wrote to connect their NXT via Bluetooth to their swing GUI. There's a transmitter and GUI class (I think you will be more interested in the transmitter class) I'm sure you can dissect yourself. It may not be 100% what you're looking for with step-by-step instructions, but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks for your help dear. :D I'll deeply try to find what I want.